# Nodejs: Passport-local vs custom user auth

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I'm fairly new to Nodejs/ExpressJS, however I have enough experience in web backend development in ROR.

I created a small web application in Node/Express using passport-local. and since I was using Mongodb, there was even a plugin for that https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose. I used this.

```
var User = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
});
```

I'm able to signup/login/logout. so a basic app is working.

Now My question is that,  is using passport good if I have only `local` authentication approach.(no social login needed).
thats mean  authentication using`express and mongoose` only, no extra plugin.

if yes how could I do the authentication using these only, any source or hint?

in case if I have to use passport(or you recommend passport because this support authentication middle-ware, I'm not sure about this though), how can i ignore `passport-local-mongoose` to create user model and authentication using passport and express only.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own Authentication Handler for passport which is connected to any source containing your logins.

```
// And this handler to your local strategy initialization
var localStrategyHandler = function (email, password, done) {

    // Here you can write any function which validates the email and password against the storage yo've used
    Accounts.getAccount(username, password).then(function (account) {
        if (account !== null) {
            return done(null, account); // If login attempt was successfull return a user object using the done callback
        } else {
            return done(null, false, 'ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND'); // If login failed return a failure like this example
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        return done('LOGIN_ERROR');
    });
};

 // Thats how you initilize a strategyHandler
 passport.use(new LocalStrategy(localStrategyHandler));
```

Function `done`is the callback method to trigger passports further behavior.